# Xcode breakpoints not showing current objects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, breakpoints

I've recently run into a really frustrating problem. When I set a breakpoint, and my program stops, the objects aren't shown in Xcode. I don't get the typical 'self' or any of my other objects. I tried restarting Xcode and my computer. I don't really know what else to do.

I'm running Xcode 4.6.1. Has anyone else run into this problem?

[image]

Comment: May not be a solution, but, I had this issue once and I just closed xcode/simulator and restarted. Seemed to work.

Comment: Can you print the objects manually?  (ie `po obj` or `p primitive`)

Comment: Yes - I can print the objects with NSLog. The console is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually get this error when I have compiler optimization turned on. The compiler will generate code which does not necessarily follow your code logic flow.

Go to your project in the navigator -> Target -> Build settings -> Search for optimization level -> expand optimization level -> select the debug line -> change to none in both columns of your project and target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm... I just checked this setting and it was already set to none.

Comment: On both debug and run under that option?

Comment: I only have debug and release. I don't understand...I never touched these fields and this randomly started happening yesterday.